# Is it possible to generate POJO classes with Jackson annotations from Fhir XML schema (.xsd) or Fhir JSON schema?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, jsonschema

in the JDK we can use `xjc *.xsd` command to generate POJO. The generated classes will have XML annotations, for example `jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType`.

But I'm interested in POJOs with Jackson annotations, for example `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`. I'm wondering if it is feasible to accomplish this task. If it is, please provide guidance on the necessary steps (algorithm) to take.

Resources:
You could download it: https://hl7.org/fhir/hl7.fhir.r5.core.tgz

1. Fhir JSON schema is located in the `hl7.fhir.r5.core.tgz\package\openapi\fhir.schema.json`
2. Fhir XML schema (.xsd) is located in the `hl7.fhir.r5.core.tgz\package\xml\**`

I tried different approaches, for instance:

1. Convert .xsd to JSON schema using the plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19024-xsd-to-json-schema
2. Generate Pojo with JSON schema using the library https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo
3. As a result, classes were generated, but not correctly and not in the amount that would have been generated with `xjc`

There were other attempts, but they were pointless. Therefore, I see no point in describing them.